# Blocked by CORS policy No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, html, api, heroku, cors

I'm currently making a project to put up "Post" from mysql onto a website and then they can also be updated from the website into Mysql. My insert function works fine because I can add post like nothing. Whenever I try and delete a post it gives me a long CORS policy error. I've looked all over the internet for an answer, but haven't found a solution. I've tried installing the CORS extensions in chrome and to also change the header into no cors. I'm the owner of the API being used.

index.js

```
const baseUrl = "**redacted for security**"
//const baseUrl = "https://localhost:5001/api/post"
//update
function getPost(){
    //const allPostsApi = "https://localhost:5001/api/post";
    const allPostsApi = baseUrl;

    fetch(allPostsApi).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(json){
        let html = "<ul>";
        json.forEach((post)=>{
            html += "<li>" + post.text + " Posted by Big Al! </li>";
        })
        html += "</ul>";
        document.getElementById("Post").innerHTML = html;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function handleOnSubmit(){
    console.log("We made it");
    var postText = document.getElementById("text").value;
    //const placeHolder = document.getElementById("Nothing").value;
    //const addPostsApi = "https://localhost:5001/api/post";
    console.log(postText);
    const addPostsApi = baseUrl;
    var text ={ 
        Text: postText
    }

    PlacePost(text);
}

function handleOnEnter(){
    console.log("We made it");
    var postId = document.getElementById("id").value;
    //const placeHolder = document.getElementById("Nothing").value;
    //const addPostsApi = "https://localhost:5001/api/post";
    console.log(postId);
    const addPostsApi = baseUrl;
    var id ={ 
        Text: postId
    }

    RemovePost(postId);
}

function PlacePost(text){
    const PlacePostUrl = baseUrl;
    fetch(PlacePostUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(text)
    }).then(response=>{
        getPost();
    })
}

function RemovePost(id){
    const RemovePostUrl = baseUrl;

    fetch(RemovePostUrl, {
        mode: 'cors',
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "Accept":'application/json',
            "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(id)
    }).then(response=>{
        getPost();
    })
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="resources/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload = "getPost()">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "scripts/index.js"></script>
    <div id="Post">

    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <form id = "addPost" onsumbit ="return false;" method = "post">
            <label for="title">Enter Post</label>
            <input type ="text" name = "text" id ="text">
            <input type ="button" value = "Submit" onclick="handleOnSubmit()">
        </form>
        <form id = "RemovePost" onsubmit ="return false;" method = "put">
            <label for ="title">Enter Post Number you wish to delete</label>
            <input type ="text" name = "text" id ="id">
            <input type ="button" value = "Submit" onclick="handleOnEnter()">
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm just very confused on how it does through on the PlacePost, but gets caught up during RemovePost. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mode: 'cors'` from your RemovePostUrl fetch.

You could set it to `same-origin` if your js is running on the same domain as your API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

You 100% do not need a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

install 'cors' by using `'npm i cors'`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
      cors({
          origin: "*"
      }
));
```

cors does not care about requests between the same origin. If you want to allow request from an within the same origin then you can set the origin value to the URL you want to request. e.g
`origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'`
And if you want to just allow all URLs to access your site you can instead use `origin: '*'` in the header and that will allow cross origin requests from any URL

Hope this helps :)